# Adding a new key to a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to add a key with a value that increases by one for every item in the nested dictionary. I have been trying to use the `dict['key']='value'` syntax but can't get it to work for a nested dictionary. I'm sure it's a very simple.

My Dictionary:

```
mydict={'a':{'result':[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'},
                        {'key1':'value3','key2':'value4'}]}}
```

This is the code that will add the key to the main part of the dictionary:

```
for x in range(len(mydict)):
        number = 1+x
        str(number)
        mydict[d'index']=number

print mydict
  #out: {d'index':d'1',d'a'{d'result':[...]}}
```

I want to add the new key and value to the small dictionaries inside the square parentheses:

```
{'a':{'result':[{'key1':'value1',...,'index':'number'}]}}
```

If I try adding more layers to the last line of the `for loop` I get a traceback error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\program.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python27\program.py", line 23, in main
    mydict['a']['result']['index']=number
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not unicode
```

I've tried various different ways of listing the nested items but no joy. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: @senderle my actual code is way too long this is a summary of it. Works for me?

Comment: @senderle please accept my apologies, I had added extra curly brackets by mistake. Amended now thank you.

Comment: @adohertyd: How about an example of the desired output?

Comment: @JoelCornett I added it there above the traceback code

Comment: Thanks @adohertyd. So if I understand you correctly, `{'result':[{'key1': 'value1', 'index': 0}, {'key1': 'valuex', 'index': 1}]}` would be correct?

Comment: @JoelCornett yes exactly except `index` first value is `1` not `0`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `mydict` is not simply a collection of nested dictionaries. It contains a list as well. Breaking up the definition helps clarify the internal structure:

```
dictlist = [{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'},
            {'key1':'value3','key2':'value4'}]
resultdict = {'result':dictlist}
mydict = {'a':resultdict}
```

So to access the innermost values, we have to do this. Working backwards:

```
mydict['a']
```

returns `resultdict`. Then this:

```
mydict['a']['result']
```

returns `dictlist`. Then this:

```
mydict['a']['result'][0]
```

returns the first item in `dictlist`. Finally, this:

```
mydict['a']['result'][0]['key1']
```

returns `'value1'`

So now you just have to amend your `for` loop to iterate correctly over `mydict`. There are probably better ways, but here's a first approach:

```
for inner_dict in mydict['a']['result']: # remember that this returns `dictlist`
    for key in inner_dict:
        do_something(inner_dict, key)
```

Comment: Ah I see now yes that's very obvious now that you point it out. Your code makes perfect sense. Thanks very much for that

Comment: @adohertyd: Notice that since the object you are interested in is a list, the indices are implicit. I can't really think of a reason why you would have to add a key to each dict within with an index if you already know the index based on the position in the list.

Comment: @JoelCornett very good point Joel. Senderle only just made me aware of the list within a dictionary so hadn't thought of that scenario. For the bigger picture of my program the `index` key would keep things uniform with my other dictionaries though. But you do make a great point

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what you're trying to do, but I think `itertools.count` would be able to help here.

```
>>> c = itertools.count()
>>> c.next()
0
>>> c.next()
1
>>> c.next()
2
>>> c.next()
3
```

... and so on.

Using this, you can keep incrementing the value that you want to use in your `dict`s

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but that's not it. I'm adding a new key to an existing dictionary. itertools is not recommended when changing/deleting keys

Comment: @adohertyd: Why would using itertools be a bad idea?

Comment: I read somewhere that using itertools to change keys (not values) can cause runtime errors and other things. I may be confused though, I'm still getting to grips with Python!

Comment: @adohertyd: Any idea where I can find this? A link maybe?

Comment: @JoelCornett It was from the Python docs: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems only refers to `iteritems()`, `iterkeys()`, and `itervalues()` apologies it seems that `itertools` is ok

Comment: @adohertyd: In this specific case, you're not iterating over the keys of the dictionary at all, so it's a non-issue.